# docker-compose restart failed with errors

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop, laradock

Recently I have upgraded docker desktop to newest version. After that I upgraded my laradock as well. When I'm going to execute **docker-compose restart** it will end up with following errors and warnings.

```
PS D:\Projects\ProjectGroup\laradock> docker-compose restart

time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSDB\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TRADER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_MSSQL\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_SSDB\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"SSDB_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"RABBITMQ_WEB_STOMP_HOST_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"NATS_CLIENT_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"NATS_MONITORING_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"NATS_ROUTE_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"TARANTOOL_ADMIN_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"MONGO_USERNAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"MONGO_PASSWORD\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"TARANTOOL_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"MINIO_ROOT_USER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"OPENRESTY_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"OPENRESTY_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"OPENRESTY_HOST_LOG_PATH\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"OPENRESTY_SITES_PATH\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"OPENRESTY_SSL_PATH\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"OPENRESTY_HOST_HTTP_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"OPENRESTY_HOST_HTTPS_PORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSDB\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-11-29T14:24:41+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TRADER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
3 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'Volumes[1]': invalid spec: :/var/log/nginx: empty section between colons
* error decoding 'Volumes[2]': invalid spec: :/etc/nginx/sites-available: empty section between colons
* error decoding 'Volumes[3]': invalid spec: :/etc/nginx/ssl: empty section between colons
```

**Docker Desktop version - 4.2.0 (70708)**

Anyone suggest solution for this will be highly appreciated.

=======================Update=======================

docker-compose.yml

```
### MySQL ################################################
mysql:
  build:
    context: ./mysql
    args:
      - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
  volumes:
    - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
  networks:
    - backend

### NGINX Server #########################################
nginx:
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    args:
      - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
      - http_proxy
      - https_proxy
      - no_proxy
  volumes:
    - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
    - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
    - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
    - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
  ports:
    - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
    - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
    - "${VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT}:81"
  depends_on:
    - php-fpm
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

Comment: Could you please share docker-compose file used here?

Comment: The errors seem to be related to nginx, but the docker-compose file you've shown includes only a MySQL container.

Comment: Updated question @Don'tPanic

Comment: At a guess, it looks like maybe those variables (`NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH`, ... etc) are not set? How are you setting them?

Comment: Actually I'm not using nginx. I'm using apache2.

Comment: Your docker compose is for nginx, and the errors seem to be related to that nginx container config.

Comment: As I said I haven't updated nginx config. I updated docker desktop only. It seems new updated effect to my laradoc environment. Do you suggest anything to do @Don'tPanic ?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your setup. You have an nginx container with problems, but you say you're using Apache. So why the nginx container?

Comment: I downgraded Docker Desktop to 4.0.0 now and it started working again as before. It seems there are compatibility issues with laradock.

Comment: By default nginx is in docker-compose.yml. I didn't change anything. After downgrade docker desktop, it works fine again. @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error, maybe you already solved it, but this is my solution by adding this env in dotenv file:

```
## OpenResty #################################################

OPENRESTY_HOST_HTTP_PORT=80
OPENRESTY_HOST_HTTPS_PORT=443
OPENRESTY_HOST_LOG_PATH=./logs/openresty/
OPENRESTY_SITES_PATH=./openresty/sites/
OPENRESTY_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
OPENRESTY_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000
OPENRESTY_SSL_PATH=./openresty/ssl/
```